# How to mock video pause function using JEST?

Tags: reactjs, testing, jestjs

In my components I have code like this:

```
this.videoRef.current.pause();
```

Where `videoRef` is `<video ref={this.videoRef} autoPlay muted > ...`

When Is `pause` reached in test, I am getting a error:

```
 Error: Not implemented: HTMLMediaElement.prototype.pause
```

How can I mock pause function?

```
    const wrapper = mount(<ComponentWithVideoTag />);

    const el = wrapper.find('video').props();
    Object.defineProperty(el, 'paused', {
        writable: true,
        value: jest.fn(),
    });
```

Not working for me.

Answer (score 28):

I wouldn't worry about trying to mock the props on the specific element, just mock the higher-level API that is being called. You can achieve this with spyOn, just be sure to call mockRestore on the stub afterwards (just in case you need it elsewhere in the file).

```
const pauseStub = jest
  .spyOn(window.HTMLMediaElement.prototype, 'pause')
  .mockImplementation(() => {})
const wrapper = mount(<ComponentWithVideoTag />);
// trigger the code that you would expect to call the pause function
expect(pauseStub).toHaveBeenCalled()
pauseStub.mockRestore()
```

Comment: why does this happen? is this a bug with jest?